# How to stop a user from tabbing past a cell when there is no hyperlink in that cell

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I've got a form in excel were the users must fill certain fields. When they come to a cell where they need to upload a Hyperlink and they don't do it, they must not be allowed to tab further/pass that cell until they upload the Hyperlink.
Will that be possible?

Comment: By form, do you mean VBA userform? Or are you using cells for this purpose?

Comment: Shrivallabha, I'm using cells for this purpose.

Comment: You need to look at sheet based event code like `Worksheet_Change` to handle this.